# Strange messages on (un)installation

Tags: gnome, apt

A lot of times when I (un)install packages, I get strange warning messages. Here's a snippet:

```
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0 ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
WARNING: node <gettext_domain> not understood below <schema>
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
```

Anyone knows what causes this? These seem like harmless messages, but what do they mean? How to I get rid of them?

[**update**] Running `sudo gconf-schemas --register-all` doesn't help, and gives me the same warning messages.

[**note**] I use Debian Squeeze.

Comment: They are Gnome warning messages. Given that Gnome's `CRITICAL` messages are commonplace and not considered bugs by the Gnome maintainers, I wouldn't worry about a mere `WARNING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep gettext /usr/share/gconf/schemas/*`. Identify the `.schemas` file containing the issue and then take action upon the related package(either reinstall or update to later version).

Anjuta for eg. had an issue just like that.

Comment: Was it a bug in Anjuta?

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=577719

Answer (score 3):

I think this has something to do with gconf2's schema files located at `/usr/share/gconf/schemas`.

Try to register the schemas again:

```
$ sudo gconf-schemas --register-all
```

`gconf-schemas(8)` says:

```
--register-all  
      clean up the GConf database and register all schemas again.  
      This might be neccessary if your gconf database becomes corrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gconf-defaults-service
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Do you have an example... which package you installed resulted in the warning messages getting displayed, which got fixed by installing **gconf-defaults-service**?